# Pass Value of Radio Button Multiple Times

Tags: javascript

I am working on some code that takes the selected value of the radio button and passes it to the next group of radio buttons to be used as input. The code works well when passing the first time, but any subsequent time, instead of passing the value, it passes "on." I think it's just something silly, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Link to JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hc3bracf/6/

Here is the HTML and JS:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="aaa">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="g1" id="i1" value="s#1" data-target="r65">
      <label id="r1" for="i1">s#1</label>
      <div class="check">
        <div class="inside"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="g1" id="i2" value="s#16" data-target="r65">
      <label id="r2" for="i2">s#16</label>
      <div class="check">
        <div class="inside"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="aaa">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="g2" id="i3" value="s#8" data-target="r66">
      <label id="r3" for="i3">s#8</label>
      <div class="check">
        <div class="inside"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="g2" id="i4" value="s#9" data-target="r66">
      <label id="r4" for="i4">s#9</label>
      <div class="check">
        <div class="inside"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="aaa">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="g33" id="i65" data-target="r97">
      <label id="r65" for="i65"></label>
      <div class="check">
        <div class="inside"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="g33" id="i66" data-target="r97">
      <label id="r66" for="i66"></label>
      <div class="check">
        <div class="inside"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="aaa">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="g49" id="i97" data-target="r113">
      <label id="r97"></label>
      <div class="check">
        <div class="inside"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="g49" id="i98" data-target="r113">
      <label id="r98"></label>
      <div class="check">
        <div class="inside"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");
for (let inp of inputs) {
  inp.addEventListener("change", function() {
    let targetLabel = document.getElementById(inp.dataset.target);
    let targetRadio = targetLabel.previousSibling;
    targetLabel.innerHTML = inp.value;
    targetRadio.value = inp.value;
    targetRadio.checked = false;
    //while there is a next target clear it
    while (targetLabel.previousSibling.hasAttribute) {
      targetLabel = document.getElementById(targetRadio.dataset.target);
      targetRadio = targetLabel.previousSibling;
      targetRadio.checked = false;
      targetLabel.innerHTML = '';
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previousSibling property returns the previous node of the specified node, in the same tree level.

The returned node is returned as a Node object.

The difference between this property and previousElementSibling, is that previousSibling returns the previous sibling node as an element node, a text node or a comment node, while previousElementSibling returns the previous sibling node as an element node (ignores text and comment nodes).

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");

for (let inp of inputs) {
  inp.addEventListener("change", function() {
    let targetLabel = document.getElementById(inp.dataset.target);
    console.log(targetLabel);
    let targetRadio = targetLabel.previousElementSibling;
    
    targetRadio.value = inp.value;
    targetLabel.innerHTML = inp.value;
   
    targetRadio.checked = false;
    //while there is a next target clear it
     while (targetLabel.previousElementSibling.hasAttribute) {
      targetLabel = document.getElementById(targetRadio.dataset.target);
      targetRadio = targetLabel.previousSibling;
      targetRadio.checked = false;
      targetLabel.innerHTML = '';
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the fix! Works like a charm!